# Wordpress wp_mail function sends email twice

Tags: wordpress

I am using a cron event and adding a PHP code to send emails to users of my wordpress site. But due to some reason my wp_mail function is sending emails twice to all the users.

Here is my code, can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code ?

```
    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'employee',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $all_users = get_users($args);
    foreach ($all_users as $user) {
        $to = esc_html($user->user_email) ;
        
            
            // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    
    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: TEST <test@test.com>' . "\r\n";
    $subject = "Regarding auto emails"; 
        $message = "<p>Dear Employee/Consultant,</p>
    <p >Please send in your submissions</p>";
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        
    }
```

Comment: How did you schedule your cron? Is there a chance it's firing twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can write mail function in this way

```
 if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){  // Condition check if mail has been sent
     continue;   // Continue to next iteration
  }
```

Comment: Hello @RameshRamGopal, please accept asma_dev's answer as the correct answer to close the question!

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP looks okay to me.

I have had luck [scheduling cron in WordPress using the approach shared here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340033/automate-a-weekly-background-function-in-wordpress/64340409?noredirect=1#comment113773883_64340409) (duplicated below). And by structuring the mail function within loops as follows:

```
<?php
$to = 'email@website.com';
$subj = 'Subject';  
$body ='
    <br/>
    Dear Recipient,<br/>
    <br/>
    Here is an email.<br/>
    <br/>';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'From: Website.com <email@website.com>' . "\r\n";
wp_mail( $to, $subj, $body, $headers ); 
?>
```

You can install a plugin like [Cron Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-cron-manager) to verify that the cron event is scheduled. "custom_cron_event" (or whatever name you choose for your function) should be listed as a scheduled cron if you've activated the plugin and it is working correctly.

Cron schedule via plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Plugin
Plugin URI: 
Description: Adds function on cron
Author: 
Version: 1.0
*/

/*  
 * When this plugin is activated, schedule
 */ 
    function activate_custom_cron(){
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'do_custom_cron_event');
    }
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate_custom_cron');

/*  
 * When this plugin is deactivated, clear_schedule cron
 */ 
    function deactivate_custom_cron(){  
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook('do_custom_cron_event');    
    }
    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'deactivate_custom_cron');


/*  
 * Function
 */ 
    function custom_cron_event() {

    /*
     * This is where your function goes
     */

    }   
    add_action( 'do_custom_cron_event', 'custom_cron_event' );

?>
```